# How does this artist skew this shape in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, skew

I was watching a tutorial on YouTube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TGOjbuOKpI0)- Skip to minute 2:33;

The artist is suddenly copying and skewing a shape - the dark background shape - at the same time. Here's a gif to show exactly what I'm referring to:

[image]

As far as my knowledge goes in Illustrator, I can skew a shape by using the the Shear tool. First I have to set a reference from which the shape should be skewed/ sheared.

I've tried searching in Adobe documentations and questions, but never found an answer. How does he do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch to the **Free Transform Tool** (e) and hold down the <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd> key when dragging a handle.

[image]

Comment: I tried with Ctrl, but it does not work! Without holding Ctrl it works well like it should I guess, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @AndrewMk Depending in you're on Apple (CMD) or Windows (CTRL), not both at the same time

Comment: @Emilie can I ask.. does a Windows keyboard have a Command or CMD key? I didn't think they did.

Comment: @Scott No CMD key on Windows. All shortcuts involving CMD are converted to CTRL on PC. But since Apple has a CTRL I can imagine the standard CMD/CTRL formula can become confusing if someone is novice and on Apple as it might suggest the need to press both.

Comment: Well Apple has "control"  not CTRL.. always lowercase and never abbreviated to "ctrl"  -- I was curious because I don't want to be overly confusing :) I can see your point.. it's more about Windows users moving to Apple since CTRL is called "Control". Thanks!